# What's the meaning of "that" in this content?

Tags: word-usage

> 'Little pig, what! are you here before me? Are they nice apples?'
>
> 'Yes, very,' said the little pig. 'I will throw you down one.'
>
> And he threw it so far, **that**, while the wolf was gone to pick it up,
>   the little pig jumped down and ran home. The next day the wolf came
>   again, and said to the little pig:

This is from "The story of The Three Little Pigs" in English fairy tales.

What's the meaning of "that" in this content?

Comment: It's a way of denoting cause and effect. "He threw it so far" being the cause, and "while the wolf was gone, the pig jumped down and ran home" was the effect. However, the emphasis here is on the distance of the throw. If he hadn't thrown the apple as far, the pig wouldn't have been able to jump down and run away.

Comment: "How far did he throw it? He threw it so far that he had to go a very long distance to find it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That" in your example is a conjunction which heads a clause that indicates an effect after a cause. For example:

> I was so tired (cause) **that** I couldn't join the party (effect).

Your example could be rephrased to:

> And he threw it so far (cause), that the little pig jumped down and ran home (effect), while the wolf was gone to pick it up.

It means the reason why the little pig jumped down and ran home was that he threw it too far.

You can visit [the link](http://www.grammarbank.com/so-that-such-that.html) to see more examples.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Glad it helped. You can wait for a couple of days before accepting an answer as there could be a more helpful and better-researched answer. You can always change the acceptance if you find more helpful answer. :-)

Comment: @Rathony Is it fair to say this usage of 'that' is explicit to this particular usage of "so"? i.e., 'I ate so much, that I couldn't eat any more' or 'I slept so little, that I passed out', etc

Comment: I think this sentence is a bit odd. I would say "threw it so far, that the pig had enough time to jump down and run home while the wolf was gone." That's not in the tone of a fairy tale though. The effect of throwing the apple wasn't that the pig jumped down, it was that the wolf was gone long enough for the pig to escape. I think there may be more to this sentence grammatically, but I can't explain why it seems wrong to me.